# Why is $f(x)=\sin (2x-\pi)$ the same as $g(x)=-\sin(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is $f(x)=\sin (2x-\pi)$ the same as $g(x)=-\sin(2x)$. Wolfram Alpha gives me this result?

Where is the mistake in my reasoning?:

- Step A: I start with $f(x)=\sin(x)$ It's period is $2\pi$.
- Step B: Then when I plot $f(x)=\sin(x-\pi)$ it is just $sin(x)$ moved to right my the amount of $\pi$, so I take the graph of $\sin(x)$ and move it to the right. It goes down when $\sin(x)$ goes up - so the following appears to be right: $$\sin(x-\pi)=-sin(x)$$
- Step C: I take $\sin(x-2\pi)$ - I move $\sin(x)$ to right by its period so it is $\sin x$ again: $$\sin(x-2\pi)=\sin(x) $$
- Step D: Now I take $f(x)=\sin(2x)$ and plot it. Its period is $\pi$.
- Step E: I move $\sin(2x)$ by its period ($\pi$) to the right. - Now I get $f(x)=\sin(2x-\pi)$.
- In Step C I have seen that if I move a periodic function by its period to the right I get the function again. So the following should be true: $$\sin(2x-\pi)=\sin(2x)$$
- This is not the same as $-\sin(2x)$.

Where is my mistake???

Comment: The period of $\sin$ is $2\pi$, not $\pi$.

Comment: Well, that's what I've written. And in step C I move it by $2\pi$.

Comment: Step E: If you move $\sin(2x)$ by $\pi$ you get $\sin(2(x - \pi)) = \sin(2x - 2\pi) = \sin(2x)$. What you have actually done is moved it right by $\pi/2$ which is only half a period, hence the negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin(2x-\pi)=\sin2x\cos\pi-\cos2x\sin\pi=\sin2x(-1)-\cos2x(0)$$

---

$\displaystyle\sin(2x-\pi)=\sin[-(\pi-2x)]=-\sin(\pi-2x)$

Use $\sin(-y)=-\sin y$

and $\displaystyle\sin(\pi-z)=\sin z$

Comment: Thanks for your perfect answer! Can you also show me _my mistake_ ?

Comment: @user50224 Look at my comment on your original posting.

Comment: @in_wolframAlpha_we_trust: Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Let $h(x) = \sin(2x)$. Then

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
h\left(x - \frac \pi 2\right) &=& \sin\left( 2 \left(x - \frac \pi 2\right) \right) \\
&=& \sin\left( 2 x - \pi \right)\\
&=& f(x).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So we see that $f(x)$ is actually $\sin(2x)$ shifted to the right through a distance $\frac \pi 2$, which is half its period. Your mistake was you assumed it was shifted by a distance $\pi$, which is not true.